# How can I use parameters in the ActiveAdmin's dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I'm showing a lot of graphs and aggregated data in the ActiveAdmin's dashboard, but I would like to make it more flexible for the user, so after a lot of work I made a form in the dashboard using a partial where the user can choose a date range and other options. These parameters should be used to filter the data shown in ActiveAdmin's dashboard...

The problem is I discovered I can't access to the `params` method in an `ActiveAdmin register_page`. The exact error I'm getting is the following: `undefined local variable or method 'params' for #<ActiveAdmin::PageDSL:0x005585abf414c0>`

So, is there a way to fix this? The only thing I'm capable of think is to execute another controller/action to save the data submited by the user in the form directly into the database and then redirect the user to the ActiveAdmin's dashboard. Finally I would use that data saved in the database to filter what should I show in the Dashboard, **but I think it's not a good practice to use the database to pass parameters**... Any ideas? What can I do?

Comment: Within the ``content ... do`` block, you do have access to the params. Could you be more precise on where in the register_page do block you want to access the ``params``?

Comment: True, you are correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This does show the params:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do
  menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }
  content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
    columns do
      column do
        panel 'Params' do
          params.inspect
        end
      end
    end
 end
```